# Capybara look through whole page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

How to set up `capybara` to  search through whole page?

i have button which located almost in the end of page,so need to scroll down to see it,and `capybara` can't find it.

```
find('a.to_blog_root', text: 'Main page').click
```

I use `selenium driver`

Comment: Capybara should be set up to look through the whole page by default. Can you post your entire page source code so we can ensure your finder is correct?

Comment: I'm looking for it    `= link_to Main page',posts_path,class:'button button_type_default to_blog_root'`

Comment: I mean post your actual HTML source code after it's been rendered by the browser. For example, in your browser right click the element and select 'Inspect' or something

Comment: <a class="button button_type_default  to_blog_root" href="/blog">Main page</a>

Comment: Thanks. If you only have one link on that page called "Main Page", then you might be able to just do `click_link('Main Page')`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the html you have provided and assuming you are using the currently supported versions of selenium-webdriver (2.53.4) and Firefox (47.0.1) then the code you showed should work.  Since it's not is the case of the text you're searching for what is shown on the page (CSS can change it)? and are you 100% sure the link is actually visible on the page?  You can check that by just putting a `binding.pry`/`byebug` (depending on what you use) before the click and looking at the page in the open browser.  Since you're just clicking a link it's hard to understand why you're doing a find followed by a click and you'd probably be better off calling any of the following

```
click_on('Main page')
click_link('Main page')
click_link('Main page', href: '/blog')
click_link(href: '/blog')
```